# Debugging code I have with 2 classes and a JFrame that holds 4 JPanels

Tags: java, swing, junit, jpanel, titled-border

I am looking for help to debug this program that I have written there are, no errors but the goal is to create a frame with three panels inside of it each of which has a titled border. I am having difficulty because my prompt requires of me to make 2 constructors and 2 classes so when I call the DailySales class in main I feel it doesn't include the other class.

So basically how can I make the panels show up while still keeping two classes and two constructors and how would I add titled borders to each of the JPanels, sorry but I'm having difficulty with the Oracle tutorial.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class DailySales extends JPanel {

    final int lPizzaPrice = 12;
    final int mPizzaPrice = 9;
    final int sPizzaPrice = 6;
    final int bSticksPrice = 3;

    final double tax = .06;
    final int dailyOper = 1000;

    String lPizza;
    String mPizza;
    String sPizza;
    String bSticks;

    int largePizza;
    int mediumPizza;
    int smallPizza;
    int breadSticks;

    int totalLargePizza;
    int totalMediumPizza;
    int totalSmallPizza;
    int totalBreadSticks;

    int totalSales;
    double totalTax;
    double netSales;
    int operCost;
    double profit;

    private FlowLayout dailyFlow;
    private Container container;

    JLabel lPizzaLabel = new JLabel("Large Pizza");//creating labels
    JLabel mPizzaLabel = new JLabel("Medium Pizza");
    JLabel sPizzaLabel = new JLabel("Small Pizza");
    JLabel bSticksLabel = new JLabel("Bread Sticks");

    JLabel totalSalesLabel = new JLabel("Total Sales");
    JLabel totalTaxLabel = new JLabel("Total Tax");
    JLabel netSalesLabel = new JLabel("Net Sales");
    JLabel dailyCostLabel = new JLabel("Daily Oper Cost");
    JLabel profitLabel = new JLabel("Profit or Loss");

    JTextField largeField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField mediumField = new JTextField(10);

    JTextField smallField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField breadField = new JTextField(10);

    JTextField totalLargeField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField totalMediumField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField totalSmallField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField totalBreadField = new JTextField(10);

    JTextField totalSalesField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField totalTaxField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField netSalesField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField dailyCostField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField profitField = new JTextField(10);

    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear Fields");//Creating buttons
    JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

    JPanel subPanel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel subPanel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel subPanel3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel top = new JPanel();

    public class GUI extends JPanel {

        public GUI() {

            subPanel1.setLayout(dailyFlow);
            subPanel1.add(lPizzaLabel, largeField);
            subPanel1.add(mPizzaLabel, mediumField);
            subPanel1.add(sPizzaLabel, smallField);
            subPanel1.add(bSticksLabel, breadField);
            subPanel1.setSize(100, 100);

            subPanel2.setLayout(dailyFlow);
            subPanel2.add(totalLargeField);
            subPanel2.add(totalMediumField);
            subPanel2.add(totalSmallField);
            subPanel2.add(totalBreadField);

            subPanel3.setLayout(dailyFlow);
            subPanel3.add(totalSalesLabel, totalSalesField);
            subPanel3.add(totalTaxLabel, totalTaxField);
            subPanel3.add(netSalesLabel, netSalesField);
            subPanel3.add(dailyCostLabel, dailyCostField);
            subPanel3.add(profitLabel, profitField);

            top.setBackground(Color.red);
            JLabel title = new JLabel("Eve's Pizza Daily Sales");
            title.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", 1, 14));
            top.add(title);
            totalSalesField.setEditable(false);//making total field uneditable
            totalTaxField.setEditable(false);
            netSalesField.setEditable(false);
            dailyCostField.setEditable(false);
            profitField.setEditable(false);
        }
    }

    public DailySales() //creating a constructor
    {

        /**
         * The constructor with all the layout informations and operators
         *
         *
         * Also adding all labels, textfields, and buttons to frame. making the
         * total field uneditable
         */
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(subPanel1);
        frame.add(subPanel2);
        frame.add(subPanel3);
        frame.add(top);
        frame.setSize(600, 450);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//initial button removes all entered text
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                largeField.setText("");
                mediumField.setText("");
                smallField.setText("");
                breadField.setText("");
                totalLargeField.setText("");
                totalMediumField.setText("");
                totalSmallField.setText("");
                totalBreadField.setText("");
                totalSalesField.setText("");
                totalTaxField.setText("");
                netSalesField.setText("");
                dailyCostField.setText("");
                profitField.setText("");
            }
        });
        calculateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//update button calculates all the inputs and displays everything
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                lPizza = largeField.getText();
                mPizza = mediumField.getText();
                sPizza = smallField.getText();
                bSticks = breadField.getText();

                largePizza = Integer.parseInt(lPizza);
                mediumPizza = Integer.parseInt(mPizza);
                smallPizza = Integer.parseInt(sPizza);
                breadSticks = Integer.parseInt(bSticks);

                totalLargePizza = (lPizzaPrice * largePizza);
                totalMediumPizza = (mPizzaPrice * mediumPizza);
                totalSmallPizza = (sPizzaPrice * smallPizza);
                totalBreadSticks = (bSticksPrice * breadSticks);

                totalLargeField.setText("" + totalLargePizza);
                totalMediumField.setText("" + totalMediumPizza);
                totalSmallField.setText("" + totalSmallPizza);
                totalBreadField.setText("" + totalBreadSticks);

                totalSales = (totalLargePizza + totalMediumPizza + totalSmallPizza + totalBreadSticks);
                totalTax = (totalSales * tax);
                netSales = (totalSales - totalTax);
                profit = (netSales - dailyOper);

                /**
                 * calculates total by adding all entered values if else
                 * statements for different situations that calculate the
                 * different between total and diet
                 */
                if (profit > 0) {
                    profitLabel.setText("Profit of ");
                } else if (profit < 0) {
                    profitLabel.setText("Loss of ");
                } else if (profit == 0) {
                    profitLabel.setText("No profit or loss ");
                }
                if (largePizza < 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quantity muist be >=0");
                } else if (mediumPizza < 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quantity muist be >=0");
                } else if (smallPizza < 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quantity muist be >=0");
                } else if (breadSticks < 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quantity muist be >=0");
                }
            }
        });
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//close button closes the program when clicked on 

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DailySales();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to order them inside the JFrame? One on top of the other, on next to the other, each taking a corner...?

Comment: Each taking a corner please, here is a screenshot of how it should look http://prntscr.com/35j92i.

Comment: And the last corner is empty?

Comment: Yes, the last corner has to be empty. I'm not sure which layout to use. I think I should be using grid layout but I don't understand how I could get the buttons to be aligned at the bottom.

Comment: Well the buttons are not added to any container so they don't appear anywhere. Can you draw \ sketch where you want everything to be. `GridLayout` does seem like the right option but there is too much unknown at this time.

Comment: Also add how do you want the components inside the panels to be aligned. You used illegal functions in some places.

Comment: Did you see the link I sent? here it is again prntscr.com/35j92i. That's how it is supposed to turn out. Here is what happens when other inputs are entered. http://prntscr.com/35je1k

Comment: OK. Meanwhile I suggest you read about [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and figure out how you would do it.

Comment: My problem isn't that I don't understand how layout managers work. It is more the fact that when I have two classes and two different constructors which relate to one another, I don't know how to make it run and display everything correctly

Comment: First of all you don't need 2 classes and 2 constructors, you can do with 1 and you will do better this way. Secondly, you have too many fields. All the labels don't need to be fields because you don't refer to them later. Also define constants as `private final static` and use capital letters for them.

Comment: And I don't think you understand layout managers if you call `subPanel1.add(lPizzaLabel, largeField);` where the 2nd argument is actually a layout constraint and not another component.

Comment: My assignment requires 2 classes and 2 constructors or else I wouldn't be posting. One for the GUI and the other for the calculations. Could you please help debug it in this form. I need it by midnight and also I need to know what layout to put it in.

Comment: Yes. Use `BorderLayout` for the frame, on the top put the title, in the middle put a panel with `GridLayout` containing the 3 panels, and on the bottom put a panel containing the 3 buttons.

Comment: Could you edit my code so I can see how it looks in the code. I really need some help, I can't think clearly been coding since 6 in the morning and it's a bit difficult for me to comprehend at the moment. Sorry for bothering you so much but I would really appreciate if you could fix up the code and post it. I'm going to try and fix it myself but just in case could you fix it up.

Comment: I already fixed it, I just don't want to do the assignment for you. I mean, I'll post it but it's like I'm doing your HW for you...

Comment: Yeah, I understand what your saying. Well I have written all this code from scratch and am editing it as you said atm. But I'm afraid it's going to take me too long so I want something to understand how it is done correctly and check my code off. The professor and tutors at the school help debug the code but I left my work for sunday and I neither can communicate with the professor nor with the teachers at this time.

Comment: I can't really do anything more unless I take hours trying to find the solution but I want to finish really soon so I can study for a math exam tomorrow. Sorry for blabbering so long.

Comment: Recommending this question is closed as overly broad.

Answer (score 1):

There's still a lot you can do to make this better, but this works.

```
public class DailySales extends JPanel {

    final int lPizzaPrice = 12, mPizzaPrice = 9, sPizzaPrice = 6, bSticksPrice = 3;

    final double tax = .06;
    final int dailyOper = 1000;

    String lPizza, mPizza, sPizza, bSticks;
    int largePizza, mediumPizza, smallPizza, breadSticks, totalLargePizza,
            totalMediumPizza, totalSmallPizza, totalBreadSticks;

    int totalSales;
    double totalTax;
    double netSales;
    int operCost;
    double profit;

    JLabel lPizzaLabel     = new JLabel("Large Pizza");
    JLabel mPizzaLabel     = new JLabel("Medium Pizza");
    JLabel sPizzaLabel     = new JLabel("Small Pizza");
    JLabel bSticksLabel    = new JLabel("Bread Sticks");
    JLabel totalSalesLabel = new JLabel("Total Sales");
    JLabel totalTaxLabel   = new JLabel("Total Tax");
    JLabel netSalesLabel   = new JLabel("Net Sales");
    JLabel dailyCostLabel  = new JLabel("Daily Oper Cost");
    JLabel profitLabel     = new JLabel("Profit or Loss");

    JTextField largeField       = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField mediumField      = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField smallField       = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField breadField       = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField totalLargeField  = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField totalMediumField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField totalSmallField  = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField totalBreadField  = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField totalSalesField  = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField totalTaxField    = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField netSalesField    = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField dailyCostField   = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField profitField      = new JTextField(10);

    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear Fields");// Creating buttons
    JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

    JPanel subPanel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel subPanel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel subPanel3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel top = new JPanel();

    public class GUI extends JPanel {
        public GUI() {

            subPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
            subPanel1.add(lPizzaLabel);
            subPanel1.add(largeField);
            subPanel1.add(mPizzaLabel);
            subPanel1.add(mediumField);
            subPanel1.add(sPizzaLabel);
            subPanel1.add(smallField);
            subPanel1.add(bSticksLabel);
            subPanel1.add(breadField);
            subPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel 1"));

//          subPanel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(subPanel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); // Same as next line
            subPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
            subPanel2.add(totalLargeField);
            subPanel2.add(totalMediumField);
            subPanel2.add(totalSmallField);
            subPanel2.add(totalBreadField);
            subPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel 2"));

            subPanel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
            subPanel3.add(totalSalesLabel);
            subPanel3.add(totalSalesField);
            subPanel3.add(totalTaxLabel);
            subPanel3.add(totalTaxField);
            subPanel3.add(netSalesLabel);
            subPanel3.add(netSalesField);
            subPanel3.add(dailyCostLabel);
            subPanel3.add(dailyCostField);
            subPanel3.add(profitLabel);
            subPanel3.add(profitField);

            JLabel title = new JLabel("Eve's Pizza Daily Sales");
            title.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", 1, 14));
            top.add(title);
            top.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

            totalSalesField.setEditable(false);// making total field uneditable
            totalTaxField.setEditable(false);
            netSalesField.setEditable(false);
            dailyCostField.setEditable(false);
            profitField.setEditable(false);
        }
    }

    public DailySales() // creating a constructor
    {
        /**
         * The constructor with all the layout informations and operators Also
         * adding all labels, textfields, and buttons to frame. making the total
         * field uneditable
         */

        new GUI();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        mainPanel.add(subPanel1);
        mainPanel.add(subPanel2);
        mainPanel.add(subPanel3);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(clearButton);
        buttonPanel.add(calculateButton);
        buttonPanel.add(exitButton);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setSize(600, 450);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// initial button
                                                            // removes all
                                                            // entered text
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                largeField.setText("");
                mediumField.setText("");
                smallField.setText("");
                breadField.setText("");
                totalLargeField.setText("");
                totalMediumField.setText("");
                totalSmallField.setText("");
                totalBreadField.setText("");
                totalSalesField.setText("");
                totalTaxField.setText("");
                netSalesField.setText("");
                dailyCostField.setText("");
                profitField.setText("");
            }
        });

        calculateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// update button
                                                                // calculates
                                                                // all the
                                                                // inputs and
                                                                // displays
                                                                // everything
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                lPizza = largeField.getText();
                mPizza = mediumField.getText();
                sPizza = smallField.getText();
                bSticks = breadField.getText();
                largePizza = Integer.parseInt(lPizza);
                mediumPizza = Integer.parseInt(mPizza);
                smallPizza = Integer.parseInt(sPizza);
                breadSticks = Integer.parseInt(bSticks);
                totalLargePizza = (lPizzaPrice*largePizza);
                totalMediumPizza = (mPizzaPrice*mediumPizza);
                totalSmallPizza = (sPizzaPrice*smallPizza);
                totalBreadSticks = (bSticksPrice*breadSticks);
                totalLargeField.setText(""+totalLargePizza);
                totalMediumField.setText(""+totalMediumPizza);
                totalSmallField.setText(""+totalSmallPizza);
                totalBreadField.setText(""+totalBreadSticks);
                totalSales = (totalLargePizza+totalMediumPizza+totalSmallPizza+totalBreadSticks);
                totalTax = (totalSales*tax);
                netSales = (totalSales-totalTax);
                profit = (netSales-dailyOper);
                /**
                 * calculates total by adding all entered values if else
                 * statements for different situations that calculate the
                 * different between total and diet
                 */
                if (profit>0) {
                    profitLabel.setText("Profit of ");
                } else if (profit<0) {
                    profitLabel.setText("Loss of ");
                } else if (profit==0) {
                    profitLabel.setText("No profit or loss ");
                }
                if (largePizza<0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quantity muist be >=0");
                } else if (mediumPizza<0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quantity muist be >=0");
                } else if (smallPizza<0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quantity muist be >=0");
                } else if (breadSticks<0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quantity muist be >=0");
                }
            }
        });

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// close button
                                                            // closes the
                                                            // program when
                                                            // clicked on
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DailySales();
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you so much for your help. I had to change it up a bit to match the prompt but you saved me so much time.

Comment: You're welcome. Just be sure you will be able to reproduce it. Good luck on the math test. (And you can accept the answer to "close the case" if you deem it so.)